# Call Solr4 rest services from Java with certificate

Tags: java, solr, certificate, alfresco, appdynamics

I need to call Solr Rest services from Java, basically I need to be able to call such things: `/solr4/alfresco/admin/plugins?wt=json` and so on.

I always get `401` error code with `No client certificate chain in this request`. I run my Java program simply with:

```
java -jar myJar.jar.
```

The question is what certificate should I provide? [browser.p12](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ssl-protect-solrwebapp.html) or some other? And preferably would be to add it as a Java option.

Comment: Where's the code you're using to make the call to SOLR?

Comment: Yes, you should provide browser.p12 located in alfresco-home\alf_data\keystore.

Comment: doesn't work... how I should call it?